# How to minimize gap between Tab icon and Tab text in Codename one?

Tags: codenameone, gui-builder

I am writing an App with Codename One, but I cannot find out how to make the gap between a tab icon and a tab text smaller.

It looks like this:

[image: currently]

but it should look like this: (With the icons of the first picture though)

[image: should]

How can I minimize the gap between

```
Icon -> text
```

and

```
Icon -> content
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gap seems to be delivered from the icon itself and not from us. Assuming you used the material design icons make sure to set the padding to 0 e.g.

```
FontImage.setDefaultPadding(0);
```

Or:

```
FontImage i = ...;
i.setPadding(0);
```

E.g:

```
Form hi = new Form("Tabs", new BorderLayout());
Tabs t = new Tabs();
FontImage fim = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, "Tab", 4);
fim.setPadding(0);
t.addTab("AAA", fim, new Label("Tab 1"));
t.addTab("BBB", fim, new Label("Tab 2"));
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, t);

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: I will try on thursday, thanks for your help, but I think I set the padding to 0

Comment: Notice this isn't the padding of the component

Comment: Oh, you are right, this could be it. I  tell you tomorrow

Comment: I tried this, neither setting the default padding, nor setting the padding of the image, nor setting the padding of the tabs works...

Comment: I updated the answer with a visual test case of my answer

Comment: I changed adding the icon in the way you did, now it works. Thank you, once again!